# Trying to get property of non-object in php class

Tags: php

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3VQm.png)I make a one function to fetch the data from database in php.I used the return value of another function for select the id from the database.But when i store worker id into array i get the error "Trying to get property of non-object" like this.What i do?I wan to store match id according to query into one array.

```
 public function getWorkers()
    {
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $orderid=$this->getTodayOrder();
        $workersId=array();
        foreach($orderid as $workers1)
        {

            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM #__orderassignment WHERE orderid='".$workers1."'";
            $db->setQuery($query2);
            $result1 = $db->loadObjectList();
            $workersId[]=$workers1->workers;
        }
         return $workersId;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the output of print_r($result1)

Comment: It gives the array which is matched into the database.I add a picture of print_r($result1)

Comment: You are trying to access array as an Object. Make sure your return type is an array or Object.

Answer (score 1):

if array is given then you need to access it like this

```
$workersId[]=$workers1['workers'];
```

Comment: Its not work.I get all the records from database.It is not working as my where condition